# Most efficient way to collect a list of values in a column Pandas - Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Below I have a logic that for each row in the dataframe test collects all values for id that has level lower than the current row and shares id_group.

This code is very slow when I apply it to my real world dataset. Is it possible to do something similar using numpy?

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'id_group':[10]*10+[11]*5,
             'level':list(range(0,10)) + list(range(0,5)),
             'id':[i+20 for i in list(range(0,10))]+[i+30 for i in list(range(0,5))]})

def unique_id(row):
    threshold = row['level']
    main_id = row['id_group']
    unique_values = test[(test['level'] < threshold) & (test.id_group==main_id)]['id'].unique()
    return unique_values.tolist()

test['list of ids'] = test.apply(lambda row: unique_id(row), axis=1)
```

Comment: working with lists in a dataframe is inherently inefficient, why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @mozway For each 'id' I want to collect the other 'ids' with the same id_group but with a lower level. These are related id's downstream. I need to check these related id's status for each id. Perhaps a list is not the way to go.

Comment: @Henri, does the initial order of records matter?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming levels are unique within a group, you could rewrite your code to use sorted values:

```
def to_list(g):
    s = g.sort_values(by='level')['id']
    out = [[]]
    for x in s.iloc[:-1]:
        out.append(out[-1]+[x])
    return pd.Series(out, index=s.index)
    
test['list of ids'] = test.groupby('id_group').apply(to_list).droplevel(0)
```

Output (with a modified input to better demonstrate the code):

```
    id_group  level  id                           list of ids
0         10      0  20                                    []
1         10      1  21                                  [20]
2         10      2  22                              [20, 21]
3         10      3  23                          [20, 21, 22]
4         10      4  24                      [20, 21, 22, 23]
5         10      5  25                  [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
6         10      8  26      [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 29, 27]
7         10      7  27          [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 29]
8         10      9  28  [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 29, 27, 26]
9         10      6  29              [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
10        11      0  30                                    []
11        11      1  32                                  [30]
12        11      2  31                              [30, 32]
13        11      3  34                          [30, 32, 31]
14        11      4  33                      [30, 32, 31, 34]
```

If you want to ensure uniqueness of the ids, rather use a `set`, it will also be more efficient:

```
def to_sets(g):
    s = g.sort_values(by='level')['id']
    out = [set()]
    for x in s.iloc[:-1]:
        out.append(out[-1]|{x})
    return pd.Series(out, index=s.index)
    
test['sets of ids'] = test.groupby('id_group').apply(to_sets).droplevel(0)
```

Output:

```
    id_group  level  id                           sets of ids
0         10      0  20                                    {}
1         10      1  21                                  {20}
2         10      2  22                              {20, 21}
3         10      3  23                          {20, 21, 22}
4         10      4  24                      {20, 21, 22, 23}
5         10      5  25                  {20, 21, 22, 23, 24}
6         10      8  26      {20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 27, 29}
7         10      7  27          {20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 29}
8         10      9  28  {20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 29}
9         10      6  29              {20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25}
10        11      0  30                                    {}
11        11      1  32                                  {30}
12        11      2  31                              {32, 30}
13        11      3  34                          {32, 30, 31}
14        11      4  33                      {32, 34, 30, 31}
```